# how to give reference to a collection of tabpages from form1 in form2 (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, collections

I tried following,

on form1,

```
Dim removedtabs as New Collection()
```

and on form2 I tried to reference it as follows,

```
form1.ControlCollection(removedtabs)
```

but it gives an error.

I am new to vb.net and never used control collection.

thanks

Comment: That's not close.  Make it Public and use form1.removedtabs.  Many ways to make that prettier.  You'll need to read a book about Winforms programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Forms are just ordinary classes, and members of classes are **Private** by default. You will at very least need to use the keyword `Public` instead of `Dim`. But let's dig a little deeper. I see a couple additional points that need to be called out:

- You used the Collection object. There is no good reason to **ever** use this object. It exists mainly for backwards compatibility with old code. You should really be using one of the generic collection types instead.
- It looks like you're using the default form1 instance. Like the Collection class, these default instances exist mainly for backwards compatibility. You should really be creating your own instances of your form objects (no one ever said you could only have one copy of a form) and sending a reference to those instances to other classes.
- Rather than exposing the object directly, keep the declaration private. Add a property that only has a get section to return the collection.